# Which controller is better for displaying user details in cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

I have some details of user in database but i want to display details for particular user.i want to know which controller is better for that can u give me some advice.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying whether it's for iPhone/iPad or Mac, but in all cases you should read through the Human Interface Guideline documents for each to figure out where to start.  It does sound like you're wanting to show information in a table of some form, so for Mac [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), for iPhone/iPad [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

These 'getting started' pages, for the [Mac](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_UserExperience/index.html) and [iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_UserExperience_iPhone/index.html) will push you in the right direction, step-by-step.

All the documentation can be found from these points: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/, http://developer.apple.com/mac/